# MQTTのQoSについて

Tags: network, mqtt

MQTTについて勉強しています。

MQTTはTCP/IP上で動くアプリケーション層のプロトコルであるということはわかるのですが、そうするとQoS0であってもTCP/IPでACKが返されるはずです。MQTTでACKとなるメッセージを送る必要がないのでは？と感じています。

わざわざQoS1,2を利用する必要が感じられないのですが、実際に利用されているものなのでしょうか？

Comment: ACKだと通信の疎通だけ出来てもメッセージが送信出来ないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: QoSレベルが1のときはPUBLISHメッセージでデータを送信し、PUBLISH ACKが送信側に返ってきます。ただしMQTTはTCP/IP上で動いているため今の2つのメッセージにそれぞれTCPのACKパケットが返ってきています。TCPでACKが返ってきているのに、MQTTでもACKをメッセージという形で実装している理由があれば知りたいです。